# Mobile Broadband - how to obtain service provider name

Tags: c#, api, mobile

I am unable to find out how to obtain the service providers name from the windows 7 mobile broadband API.
The provider.providerName always returns a null string but the providerID is correct (23430) for EE here in the UK.

Below is show a snippet of the used to obtain this information. All the other aspects of the Mbn interface are working
including the profiles etc, but I cant find out how to get the Name!

Am I missing something? , Could any one help me out on my final issue please?

Note: Windows VAN does show the service provider.

My Many Thanks

Sarah

```
///
/// Check the reported state of this interface

    switch (readyState)
    {
        case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_INITIALIZED:

         /// interface is initialised and has active SIM
         /// so lets get service providor information
         /// 
         MBN_PROVIDER provider = mobileInterface.GetHomeProvider();

         mi.Provider = provider.providerName;       // Always ""
         mi.ProviderID = provider.providerID;       // but this is correct
         mi.ProviderState = provider.providerState;     // as is all this
         mi.Signaldbm = mbnGetSignal(mi.InterfaceID);
         mi.Signalbar = mbnConvertSignal(mi.Signaldbm);
         mi.Message = "Ready";
         break;
```

System Setup

Windows 7 Lenovo Laptop, F3507g internal modem

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided here for Configuring a Connection Programatically was my solution:
[C# Read Windows Mobile Broadband connection properties](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18577510/c-sharp-read-windows-mobile-broadband-connection-properties)

This helped me to find the ProfileName (netsh mbn show profiles) by iterating across interfaces and then calling GetConnectionProfiles() passing the interface as a parameter and then loading an XMLDocument with the IMbnConnectionProfile GetProfileXMLData

The ProfileName is in the XMLDocument["MbnProfile"]["Name"].InnerText

It seems like a lot of work but if you only have to worry about one interface and one profile you can use the first element of each array.  I'll paste my code in but it's VB

```
Dim mcpm As MbnConnectionProfileManager = New MbnConnectionProfileManager()
Dim imcpm As IMbnConnectionProfileManager = DirectCast(mcpm,  IMbnConnectionProfileManager)
Dim connectionProfiles() As IMbnConnectionProfile


Dim mim As MbnInterfaceManager = New MbnInterfaceManager()
Dim imim As IMbnInterfaceManager = DirectCast(mim, IMbnInterfaceManager)
Dim interfaceArray() As IMbnInterface = imim.GetInterfaces()

For Each i As IMbnInterface In interfaceArray
    connectionProfiles = imcpm.GetConnectionProfiles(i)
    For Each c As IMbnConnectionProfile In connectionProfiles
        Dim doc As System.Xml.XmlDocument = New System.Xml.XmlDocument()
        doc.LoadXml(c.GetProfileXmlData())

        cmbMBNProfileName.Items.Add(doc("MBNProfile")("Name").InnerText)
    Next
Next
```