# C# Read Windows Mobile Broadband connection properties

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, mobile-broadband-api

First up, here's the background:

We have a Windows Forms application (written in C#, .NET Framework 3.5) currently running on full Windows 7 tablets, which have a 3G module built in that is used for data connectivity. The data connection is configured as a normal mobile broadband connection in Windows (so Windows manages the connectivity itself), and the connection shows up in Control Panel > Network and Internet > Network Connections and it works fine - the application is able to communicate over the internet with our web service. We will be moving onto a different device (likely a full Windows 8-based tablet) at some point in the future.

Now, what I need to do is read the connection status of this Mobile Broadband connection; i.e. get the signal strength, and the carrier name (e.g. Vodafone UK). I've found a way to do this using the Mobile Broadband API part of the Windows 7 SDK (see [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd323271%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/hardware/gg487392.aspx)), however this appears to be OS specific as it doesn't work on Windows 8 - or at least not with the device I have here.

Is there a generic way to read the mobile broadband connection properties using the .NET framework?

Alternatively, does anyone know of a Windows 8 SDK which contains a Mobile Broadband API like the Windows 7 one I'm currently using?

Thanks in advance.

Update - I've got this working on a range of different Win 7 / Win 8 devices now. Even the Lenovo device is working OK. I'll post up example code for the main bits (Reading connection status, configuring the connection, checking the SIM status) as answers; the code is a little too long to go into the question, annoyingly.

Comment: I've added most of the code I ended up using for testing as answers below. Your own code likely won't be littered with MessageBoxes, but hopefully others will find the examples useful.

Comment: Hi, how did you get this to work on windows 8? mbnInfMgrInterface = null, when i try the same on windows 8... do I require an addition install or is the Interop.MbnApi.dll enough?

Comment: All the Win 8 devices I tried came back with an IMbnInterfaceManager - though it didn't work on anything without a mobile broadband adapter (e.g. my desktop PC).

What device is it, and does the adapter work when manually configured in Windows?

Comment: hey Paul F, thanks for your answer, I got it to work. my mistake, I just copied paste your code and saw afterwards that there are cases that where not handled "do nothing"... I've got things to work on windows 8 now. I didn't have visual studio on my tablet so I couldn't test exactly... I assumed that the imbninterfacemanager was null, but it wasn't... sorry, my mistake... Upvoted your response...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Mobile Broadband API is also available in Windows 8 Desktop.

If you're using Windows 8 Metro/RT/whatever name, you need [these WindowsRT APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391779.aspx)
(Windows.Connectivity.NetworkInformation etc).

Comment: I've managed to get the Mobile Broadband API working in on a Win8 tablet now. It doesn't work on all Win8 machines for some reason, I think it's due to the funny way some machines have their mobile data connection set up (e.g. the Lenovo Thinkpad Tablet 2, which has a mobile broadband modem, but it is configured to emulate an ethernet adaptor in Windows, so the Mobile Broadband API doesn't pick it up).

Comment: Is there by any chance an always-on IP connection for this ethernet adaptor, even when there's no backhaul mobile connection?

Comment: I found in the end that it wasn't anything to do with the strange pseudo-ethernet adaptor. It was just the SDK behaving slightly differently with different mobile broadband adapters. The code below works on the 4 different Win 7, Win 8, and 8.1 devices I've tried. Thank you for your help though!

Answer (score 4):

**Configuring a connection programmatically** (you will need the APN details):

```
try
        {
            MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager(); 
            IMbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgrInterface = mbnInfMgr as IMbnInterfaceManager;
            if (mbnInfMgrInterface != null)
            {
                IMbnInterface[] mobileInterfaces = mbnInfMgrInterface.GetInterfaces() as IMbnInterface[];
                if (mobileInterfaces != null && mobileInterfaces.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Just use the first interface
                    IMbnSubscriberInformation subInfo = mobileInterfaces[0].GetSubscriberInformation();

                    if (subInfo != null)
                    {
                        SIMNumber = subInfo.SimIccID;
                        // Get the connection profile
                        MbnConnectionProfileManager mbnConnProfileMgr = new MbnConnectionProfileManager();
                        IMbnConnectionProfileManager mbnConnProfileMgrInterface = mbnConnProfileMgr as IMbnConnectionProfileManager; 
                        if (mbnConnProfileMgrInterface != null)
                        {
                            bool connProfileFound = false;
                            string profileName = String.Empty;

                            try
                            {
                                IMbnConnectionProfile[] mbnConnProfileInterfaces = mbnConnProfileMgrInterface.GetConnectionProfiles(mobileInterfaces[0]) as IMbnConnectionProfile[];

                                foreach (IMbnConnectionProfile profile in mbnConnProfileInterfaces)
                                {
                                    string xmlData = profile.GetProfileXmlData();

                                    if (xmlData.Contains("<SimIccID>" + SIMNumber + "</SimIccID>"))
                                    {
                                        connProfileFound = true;
                                        bool updateRequired = false;

                                        // Check if the profile is set to auto connect
                                        XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                                        xdoc.LoadXml(xmlData);

                                        profileName = xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Name"].InnerText;

                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["ConnectionMode"].InnerText != "auto")
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["ConnectionMode"].InnerText = "auto";
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }

                                        // Check the APN settings
                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"] == null)
                                        {
                                            XmlElement context = (XmlElement)xdoc["MBNProfile"].AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Context", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                            context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("AccessString", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                            context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Compression", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                            context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("AuthProtocol", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }

                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AccessString"].InnerText != APNAccessString)
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AccessString"].InnerText = APNAccessString;
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }
                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["Compression"].InnerText != APNCompression)
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["Compression"].InnerText = APNCompression;
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }
                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AuthProtocol"].InnerText != APNAuthProtocol)
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AuthProtocol"].InnerText = APNAuthProtocol;
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }

                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"] == null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(APNUsername))
                                        {
                                            XmlElement userLogonCred = (XmlElement)xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"].InsertAfter(xdoc.CreateElement("UserLogonCred", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI), xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AccessString"]);
                                            userLogonCred.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("UserName", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                            userLogonCred.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Password", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }

                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"] != null && xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["UserName"].InnerText != APNUsername)
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["UserName"].InnerText = APNUsername;
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }

                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"] != null && xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["Password"] == null && !String.IsNullOrEmpty(APNUsername))
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"].AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Password", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                        }

                                        if (xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"] != null && xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["Password"].InnerText != APNPassword)
                                        {
                                            xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["Password"].InnerText = APNPassword;
                                            updateRequired = true;
                                        }

                                        if (updateRequired)
                                        {
                                            // Update the connection profile
                                            profile.UpdateProfile(xdoc.OuterXml);
                                        }
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                            catch (Exception ex)
                            {
                                if (!ex.Message.Contains("Element not found"))
                                {
                                    throw ex;
                                }
                            }

                            if (!connProfileFound)
                            {
                                // Create the connection profile
                                XmlDocument xdoc = new XmlDocument();
                                xdoc.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", "yes"));
                                XmlElement mbnProfile = (XmlElement)xdoc.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("MBNProfile", "http://www.microsoft.com/networking/WWAN/profile/v1"));
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Name", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = SIMNumber;
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("IsDefault", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = "true";
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("ProfileCreationType", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = "DeviceProvisioned";
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("SubscriberID", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = subInfo.SubscriberID;
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("SimIccID", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = SIMNumber;
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("HomeProviderName", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = SIMNumber;
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("AutoConnectOnInternet", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = "true";
                                mbnProfile.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("ConnectionMode", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI)).InnerText = "auto";

                                XmlElement context = (XmlElement)xdoc["MBNProfile"].AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Context", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("AccessString", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                XmlElement userLogonCred = (XmlElement)context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("UserLogonCred", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                userLogonCred.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("UserName", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                userLogonCred.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Password", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("Compression", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));
                                context.AppendChild(xdoc.CreateElement("AuthProtocol", xdoc["MBNProfile"].NamespaceURI));

                                xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AccessString"].InnerText = APNAccessString;
                                xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["UserName"].InnerText = APNUsername;
                                xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["UserLogonCred"]["Password"].InnerText = APNPassword;
                                xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["Compression"].InnerText = APNCompression;
                                xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Context"]["AuthProtocol"].InnerText = APNAuthProtocol;

                                profileName = xdoc["MBNProfile"]["Name"].InnerText;

                                mbnConnProfileMgrInterface.CreateConnectionProfile(xdoc.OuterXml); 
                            }

                            // Register the connection events
                            MbnConnectionManager connMgr = new MbnConnectionManager();
                            IConnectionPointContainer connPointContainer = connMgr as IConnectionPointContainer;

                            Guid IID_IMbnConnectionEvents = typeof(IMbnConnectionEvents).GUID;
                            IConnectionPoint connPoint;
                            connPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref IID_IMbnConnectionEvents, out connPoint);

                            ConnectionEventsSink connEventsSink = new ConnectionEventsSink();
                            connPoint.Advise(connEventsSink, out cookie); if (showProgress) { MessageBox.Show("After registering events"); }

                            // Connect
                            IMbnConnection connection = mobileInterfaces[0].GetConnection();

                            if (connection != null)
                            {
                                MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE state;
                                string connectionProfileName = String.Empty;
                                connection.GetConnectionState(out state, out connectionProfileName);

                                if (state != MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE.MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE_ACTIVATED && state != MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE.MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE_ACTIVATING)
                                {
                                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(connectionProfileName))
                                    {
                                        connectionProfileName = profileName;
                                    }
                                    uint requestID;
                                    connection.Connect(MBN_CONNECTION_MODE.MBN_CONNECTION_MODE_PROFILE, connectionProfileName, out requestID);

                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    // Do nothing, already connected
                                }
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                MessageBox.Show("Connection not found.");
                            }
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("mbnConnProfileMgrInterface is null.");
                        }
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("No subscriber info found.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No mobile interfaces found.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("mbnInfMgrInterface is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("SIM is not inserted."))
            {
                SIMNumber = "No SIM inserted.";
            }
            MessageBox.Show("LoginForm.DataConnection ConfigureWindowsDataConnection Error " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: Do you know if I can use your solution under Windows 10 (i.e. LTSB 1607)?

Answer (score 3):

**Reading the connection status**:

```
try
        {
            MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
            IMbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgrInterface = mbnInfMgr as IMbnInterfaceManager;
            if (mbnInfMgrInterface != null)
            {
                IMbnInterface[] mobileInterfaces = mbnInfMgrInterface.GetInterfaces() as IMbnInterface[];
                if (mobileInterfaces != null && mobileInterfaces.Length > 0)
                {
                    // Use the first interface, as there should only be one mobile data adapter
                    IMbnSignal signalDetails = mobileInterfaces[0] as IMbnSignal;

                    Int32.TryParse(signalDetails.GetSignalStrength().ToString(), out PhoneSignal);
                    PhoneSignal = Convert.ToInt32(((float)PhoneSignal / 16) * 100);

                    MBN_PROVIDER provider = mobileInterfaces[0].GetHomeProvider();
                    PhoneNetwork = provider.providerName.ToString();

                    if (String.IsNullOrEmpty(SIMNumber))
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            IMbnSubscriberInformation subInfo = mobileInterfaces[0].GetSubscriberInformation();

                            if (subInfo != null)
                            {
                                SIMNumber = subInfo.SimIccID;
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                SIMNumber = "Unable to read SIM info";
                            }
                        }
                        catch (Exception)
                        {
                            SIMNumber = "Unable to read SIM info";
                        }
                    }

                    // Check whether the connection is active
                    IMbnConnection connection = mobileInterfaces[0].GetConnection();

                    if (connection != null)
                    {
                        MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE state;
                        string profileName = String.Empty;
                        connection.GetConnectionState(out state, out profileName);

                        Connected = (state == MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE.MBN_ACTIVATION_STATE_ACTIVATED);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Connection not found.");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No mobile interfaces found.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("mbnInfMgrInterface is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            if (ex.Message.Contains("SIM is not inserted."))
            {
                SIMNumber = "No SIM inserted.";
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("LoginForm.DataConnection GetWindowsMobileDataStatus " + ex.Message);
            }
            PhoneSignal = 0;
            PhoneNetwork = "Unknown";
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

**Checking the SIM is inserted and working / activated**:

```
try
        {
            MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
            IMbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgrInterface = mbnInfMgr as IMbnInterfaceManager;
            if (mbnInfMgrInterface != null)
            {
                IMbnInterface[] mobileInterfaces = mbnInfMgrInterface.GetInterfaces() as IMbnInterface[];
                if (mobileInterfaces != null && mobileInterfaces.Length > 0)
                {
                    try
                    {
                        MBN_READY_STATE readyState = mobileInterfaces[0].GetReadyState();

                        switch (readyState)
                        {
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_BAD_SIM:
                                MessageBox.Show("The SIM is invalid (PIN Unblock Key retrials have exceeded the limit).");
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_DEVICE_BLOCKED:
                                MessageBox.Show("The device is blocked by a PIN or password which is preventing the device from initializing and registering onto the network.");
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_DEVICE_LOCKED:
                                MessageBox.Show("The device is locked by a PIN or password which is preventing the device from initializing and registering onto the network.");
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_FAILURE:
                                MessageBox.Show("General device failure.");
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_INITIALIZED:
                                try
                                {
                                    IMbnSubscriberInformation subInfo = mobileInterfaces[0].GetSubscriberInformation();

                                    if (subInfo != null)
                                    {
                                        SIMNumber = subInfo.SimIccID;
                                    }
                                    else
                                    {
                                        SIMNumber = "Unable to read SIM info";
                                    }
                                }
                                catch (Exception)
                                {
                                    SIMNumber = "Unable to read SIM info";
                                }

                                IMbnRegistration registration = mobileInterfaces[0] as IMbnRegistration;
                                if (registration != null)
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        MBN_REGISTER_STATE regState = registration.GetRegisterState();

                                        switch (regState)
                                        {
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_DENIED:
                                                // SIM Inactive
                                                simInactive = true;
                                                MessageBox.Show("The device was denied registration. The most likely cause of this error is an Inactive SIM.");
                                                break;
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_DEREGISTERED:
                                                // Do nothing - this is returned before the device has tried to register
                                                break;
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_HOME:
                                                // Do nothing
                                                break;
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_NONE:
                                                MessageBox.Show("The device registration state is unknown. This state may be set upon failure of registration mode change requests.");
                                                break;
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_PARTNER:
                                                // Do nothing
                                                break;
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_ROAMING:
                                                // Do nothing
                                                break;
                                            case MBN_REGISTER_STATE.MBN_REGISTER_STATE_SEARCHING:
                                                // Do nothing
                                                break;
                                            default:
                                                MessageBox.Show("GetRegisterState returned an unexpected state: " + regState.ToString());
                                                break;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch (Exception ex)
                                    {
                                        MessageBox.Show("GetRegisterState Error: " + ex.Message);
                                    }
                                }
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_NOT_ACTIVATED:
                                MessageBox.Show("The subscription is not activated.");
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_OFF:
                                MessageBox.Show("The mobile broadband device stack is off.");
                                break;
                            case MBN_READY_STATE.MBN_READY_STATE_SIM_NOT_INSERTED:
                                MessageBox.Show("The SIM is not inserted.");
                                break;
                            default:
                                MessageBox.Show("GetReadyState returned an unexpected state: " + readyState.ToString());
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("GetReadyState Error: " + ex.Message);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("No mobileInterfaces found.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                MessageBox.Show("mbnInfMgrInterface is null.");
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message);
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

**Respond to the connection events** (events are registered in the above example):

```
    public class ConnectionEventsSink : IMbnConnectionEvents
    {
        public ConnectionEventsSink() { }

        public void OnConnectComplete(IMbnConnection connection, uint requestID, int status)
        {
            // Un-register the connect event - you might not want to do this, depends on your own requirements. Do do this you need the cookie uint from when the events were registered.
            MbnConnectionManager connMgr = new MbnConnectionManager();
            IConnectionPointContainer connPointContainer = connMgr as IConnectionPointContainer;

            Guid IID_IMbnConnectionEvents = typeof(IMbnConnectionEvents).GUID;
            IConnectionPoint connPoint;
            connPointContainer.FindConnectionPoint(ref IID_IMbnConnectionEvents, out connPoint);

            connPoint.Unadvise(cookie);

            switch (status)
            {
                case 0:
                    MobileBroadbandTest.Connected = true;
                    MessageBox.Show("Connected");
                    break;
                case -2141945334:
                    MessageBox.Show("There is no SIM in the device.");
                    break;
                case -2141945328:
                    MessageBox.Show("A PIN is required for the operation to complete.");
                    break;
                case -2141945335:
                    MessageBox.Show("The network service subscription has expired.");
                    break;
                case -2141945337:
                    MessageBox.Show("The provider is not visible. This applies only to manual registration mode.");
                    break;
                case -2141945340:
                    MessageBox.Show("The connection access string is not correct.");
                    break;
                case -2141945333:
                    MessageBox.Show("An active voice call is in progress.");
                    break;
                case -2141945339:
                    MessageBox.Show("There is already an Mobile Broadband context active. The Mobile Broadband service does not currently support multiple active contexts.");
                    break;
                case -2141945336:
                    MessageBox.Show("The device radio is off.");
                    break;
                case -2141945338:
                    MessageBox.Show("No active attached packet service is available.");
                    break;
                case -2141945326:
                    MessageBox.Show("Generic Failure.");
                    break;
                case -2141945320:
                    MessageBox.Show("Profile is invalid.");
                    break;
                case -2141945319:
                    MessageBox.Show("Default profile exist.");
                    break;
                case -2141945327:
                    MessageBox.Show("PIN is disabled.");
                    break;
                case -2141945329:
                    MessageBox.Show("Pin is not supported.");
                    break;
                case -2141945330:
                    MessageBox.Show("Providers not found.");
                    break;
                case -2141945331:
                    MessageBox.Show("Device is not registered.");
                    break;
                case -2141945332:
                    MessageBox.Show("Visible provider cache is invalid.");
                    break;
                case -2141945341:
                    MessageBox.Show("Requested data class is not available.");
                    break;
                case -2141945342:
                    MessageBox.Show("Bad SIM is inserted.");
                    break;
                case -2141945343:
                    MessageBox.Show("Context is not activated.");
                    break;

                default:
                    MessageBox.Show("Unexpected status: " + status.ToString());
                    break;
            }
        }

        public void OnVoiceCallStateChange(IMbnConnection connection)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        public void OnConnectStateChange(IMbnConnection connection)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }

        public void OnDisconnectComplete(IMbnConnection connection, uint requestID, int status)
        {
            // Do nothing
        }
```

}

Comment: Note to other readers: this is crucial - you won't get informed of connections being successful/unsuccessful otherwise. Also, be sure to only register once (in general) or one gets lots of notifications. This is very different in approach to those of us use to a synchronous use of (say) RAS.